# React 16.3 Context API -- Provider/Consumer issues

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have been doing some experiment on React 16.3.1 ContextAPI. and I encountered into something that I couldn't fathom. I was hoping I could use your help.

**Note:** The problem have been solved but, its not the solution I am looking for.

Let start with first experiment on multiple components within same file  **Index.js**.

```
import React, { Component, createContext } from 'react';
const { Provider, Consumer } = createContext();

class AppProvider extends Component {
  state = {
    name: 'Superman',
    age: 100
  };

  render() {
    const increaseAge = () => {
      this.setState({ age: this.state.age + 1 });
    };

    const decreaseAge = () => {
      this.setState({ age: this.state.age - 1 });
    };
    return (
      <Provider
        value={{
          state: this.state,
          increaseAge,
          decreaseAge
        }}
      >
        {this.props.children}
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}

class Person extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="person">
        <Consumer>
          {context => (
            <div>
              <p>I'm {context.state.name}</p>
              <p>I'm {context.state.age}</p>
              <button onClick={context.increaseAge}>
                <span>+</span>
              </button>
              <button onClick={context.decreaseAge}>
                <span>-</span>
              </button>
            </div>
          )}
        </Consumer>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class App extends Component {
  render() {
      return (
        <AppProvider>
          <div className="App">
            <p>Imma Apps</p>
            <Person />
          </div>
        </AppProvider>
      );
    }
  }

export default App;
```

As result, this render out perfect without any error. I am able to see name (**Superman**) and age (**100**). I am able to increase and decrease age by 1.

As you can see, I have imported `{createContext}` from react then created `{Provider, Consumer}`. Wrapped `<Provider>` with state value and `<Consumer>`.

Next Experiment, was exact copy each component from **index.js** and paste them separately into their own files.

**AppProvider.js**

```
import React, { Component, createContext } from 'react';
const { Provider, Consumer } = createContext();

class AppProvider extends Component {
  state = {
    name: 'Superman',
    age: 100
  };

  render() {
    const increaseAge = () => {
      this.setState({ age: this.state.age + 1 });
    };

    const decreaseAge = () => {
      this.setState({ age: this.state.age - 1 });
    };
    return (
      <Provider
        value={{
          state: this.state,
          increaseAge,
          decreaseAge
        }}
      >
        {this.props.children}
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}
export default AppProvider;
```

**Person.js**

```
import React, { Component, createContext } from 'react';
const { Provider, Consumer } = createContext();

class Person extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="person">
        <Consumer>
          {context => (
            <div>
              <p>I'm {context.state.name}</p>
              <p>I'm {context.state.age}</p>
              <button onClick={context.increaseAge}>
                <span>+</span>
              </button>
              <button onClick={context.decreaseAge}>
                <span>-</span>
              </button>
            </div>
          )}
        </Consumer>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default Person;
```

**App.js**

```
import React, { Component, createContext } from 'react';
const { Provider, Consumer } = createContext();

class App extends Component {
  render() {
      return (
        <AppProvider>
          <div className="App">
            <p>Imma Apps</p>
            <Person />
          </div>
        </AppProvider>
      );
    }
  }

export default App;
```

As result, I am getting error - **TypeError: Cannot read property 'state' of undefined**.

I am unable to grasp what the exactly error was.. All I did was copy and paste each into files without changing any syntax.

Although, Alternative method was to create a new file and add syntax following...

**Context.js**

```
import { createContext } from 'react';
const Context = createContext();
export default Context;
```

Then go into each files (**AppProvider.js**. **Person.js** and **App.js**) and replace...

`import React, { Component, createContext } from 'react';`
`const { Provider, Consumer } = createContext();`'

...into...

`import Context from './Context.js';`. Also replace... `<Provider>` into `<Context.Provider>` and `<Consumer>` into `<Context.Consumer>`.

And this killed the error.  However, this is not the solution I am looking for.  I wanted to use `<Provider>` tag instead of `<Context.Provider>`.

Question is, Why am I getting this error?

Why am I unable to use this method...

`import React, { Component, createContext } from 'react';`
`const { Provider, Consumer } = createContext();`'

for each components in separate files so I could use `<Provider>` tag ?

Are there any way around to get the solution I'm looking for?

Your help is appreciated and Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your are getting ***TypeError: Cannot read property 'state' of undefined.***
Beacuse every time you call `const { Provider, Consumer } = createContext();` it creates a new object, this object need to be exported in order for consumers to consume this specific object.

So in person.js 
when you try doing `{context.state.age}` it really does not have state on this object, you just created a new Context which is empty or rather with React internal methods and properties.

So in order to **consume** the same object just export it, like you did in Context.js and instead of doing:

```
import { createContext } from 'react';
const Context = createContext();
export default Context;
```

replace to:

```
import { createContext } from 'react';
const { Provider, Consumer } = createContext();
export { Consumer, Provider };
```

Then when you want to use it in other files ( meaning import it ) just call:

```
import { Consumer, Provider } from './Context.js';
```

Comment: Thank you for your help... It worked.Except need to fix  `export { Consumer, Provider };`

Comment: @sirrus Sure, glad to help.